# Why doesn't this assign a copy

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following code and I'm wondering why it returns the same list instead of a copy:

```
x = [2,1,3]
y = x
y.sort()
print y
print x
```

Why does this return the same sorted list?

Comment: "why it returns the same list"?  Because that's the rule for `=`.  I'm unclear on what you're asking?  Are you asking for the Python definition of `=`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's modified in-place.

Python lists have reference semantics, meaning that when you assign a list to another variable, they're actually pointing at the same list.

If you want to make a copy, do this:

```
x = [2,1,3]
y = x[:]
y.sort()
print y
print x
```

The *slice* notation does cause the list (in this case, the entire list, though you can make a small modification to ask for a particular sublist) to be copied.

Comment: Everything in Python has reference semantics unless you go out of your way to fake value semantics.

Comment: Hmm...you are correct. Numbers just appear to have value semantics because they are immutable. Alright, I'll remove the offending sentence.

Comment: Numbers only *appear* to have value semantics; when you say `a=a+b`, you're creating a new number that is the sum and reassigning the name `a` to that sum. The old contents of `a` are still in memory, waiting to be garbage collected.

Comment: Mark: Yes, this is what I was referring to in my comment just above yours. As I said, corrected.

Comment: wait, so what is happening when you say `x=1 \n y=x \n x=2` ?

Comment: You're creating a value `1`, then assigning it to `x`. Then you're assigning the same value to `y`. Then you're creating another new value `2`, and changing x to point at the `2` rather than the `1`. Whereas when you use the `sort()` method, you're asking a particular value to mutate itself in-place. Fortunately, the numbers don't have any such methods, so you can treat them as though they have value semantics.

Comment: I see that makes sense. So that's what you mean when py is reference based but 'appears' to not be in the case just presented.

Answer (score 4):

You are dealing with *references* in Python. The statement `y = x` makes `y` point to the same thing as `x`, so changes to `y` are reflected in `x` (because they point to the same underlying list).

You can change a copy by doing:

```
y = list(x) # make a copy of the list so we can change y without disturbing x
y.sort()
```

or

```
y = sorted(x) # return a new sorted copy of what is in x
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the function that directly gives the OP what is desired.

Comment: +1 from me too, but that's really a specialized answer to a specialized question. The more general answers are useful as well.

Answer (score 2):

x is the name of ("reference to") the list (object). The line

```
y=x
```

merely makes y another name for the same list. If you want to copy the list, use one of

```
y = x[:]
y = list(x)
```

(The first syntax is just an ordinary list slice, but with both the start and the end values left out, meaning that it takes the entire list.)

Note that a list is a list of objects, and copying the list will not copy the objects. If you want that behaviour — a *deep* copy — you must do so explicitly with

```
import copy
y = copy.deepcopy(x)
```

Naturally, this will be slower.

Comment: I prefer `list(x)`; explicit is better than implicit, and the `[:]` trick doesn't generalize nearly as well.

Comment: @Karl: `[:]` is explicit, just less obvious to someone not well versed in the idioms of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a list to another variable in Python creates a reference, so any changes you make to the reference will show up in the original. If you want a copy that will not alter the original, do this:

```
y = x[:]
```

Comment: -1: `x[:]` _is_ a shallow copy. `copy.deep copy` is a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only copy the reference.

For instruction on how to clone the list ('deep copy'),see:
[How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

When you say `y = x`, you're really just assigning another name (y) to the contents of x. If x is a mutable value and you do something to change it, you change the one-and-only copy that has 2 different names.

A common way to prevent this is to assign to a slice, which is always a copy of the original list.

```
y = x[:]
```